# Ansible expect responses were feed twice

Tags: ansible

My Ansible code:

```
- expect:
    command: virsh console myguest
    responses:
      'Escape character is': ''
      'login:': 'root'
      'root@:~ #': 'cli'
      'root>': 'show version'
  register: myreg
- debug: msg="{{ myreg.stdout_lines }}"
```

Execution of the code above showed each of my responses were feed twice. See sample outputs below:

```
    "login: root",
    "Last login: Mon May 10 03:57:15 on ttyu0",
    "",
    "root@:~ # root",
    "",
    "root: Command not found.",
    "root@:~ # cli",
    "",
    "cli",
    "root> cli",
    "      ^",
    "unknown command.",
    "",
    "root> show version ",
    ......
```

Although the wrong feedings were not recognized so the results were still usable, but what might be wrong that caused the double feeds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an ambiguous regex:

> ```
> "Last login: Mon May 10 03:57:15 on ttyu0",
> ```

for sure matches `login:` just with a `Last`  prefix

You likely want:

```yaml
...
    responses:
      '^login:': 'root'
      '^root@:~ #': 'cli'
```

since in your examples those strings occur at the leading edge of the output.

The rest of the malformity you're encourtering may straighten itself out once you and expect are on the same page